# My TV as a monitor has two types of 1920x1080, dependent on AMD display driver version. How can I get the one I want with newer drivers?

Tags: drivers, display, hdmi, resolution, 1080p

I am using my TV as a desktop monitor and I have an AMD video card, they are connected via HDMI cable. My TV has two different interpretations of 1920x1080 (its native resolution). One is just "1920x1080" and it is what the computer boots on and looks quite nice for reading text.

The other is "1080p" and seems to be a little more vibrant in colors, perhaps a superior mode for watching video but text is a bit janky and hurts to read after a short while. I can change the pixel format through AMD driver settings to YCbCr 4:2:2 to make the text a little better but even with extensive tweaking, it's still inferior to the "1920x1080" mode at best.

On other TVs, I've had a "PC Mode" that I could switch to for this kind of thing, but this TV doesn't have that option. Instead, it seems to choose which mode to use based on something the AMD driver is deciding on. If I connect to the HDMI port directly of the card, with any driver, I will get the "1080p" mode. If I connect to the DVI using an adapter, it will instead chose "1920x1080", so long as the driver is a certain version or under.

Some point after driver version 14.100.0.0, the DVI adapter kludge stops working. It might be worth noting that HDMI Audio and certain content DRM doesn't work with the DVI adapter solution on 14.100.0.0 and below either (Whatever Amazon uses for HD video streaming, off the top of my head). Whenever they added support for that stuff through DVI adapter, that's when my TV started picking "1080p" mode over "1920x1080".

I've been stumped on this for a long time, how can I use later drivers and force the correct signal or whatever to get "1920x1080" selected? Is it a matter of resolution timing differences? I don't know how to figure out what my current timings are, let alone mess with them. Is it the Audio/DRM support that it's detecting? I've tried not letting the audio driver install but that doesn't achieve anything. I think I've read you could disable the DRM support through bios editing of the card, but I'd rather be sure before I start messing with that.

So, can anyone help me out with this? Any ideas? Knowledge that I am over looking? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1032945/973099). As it says, using CRU to delete all extension blocks and restarting put the display back to 1920x1080, even with a straight HDMI connection. Loss of audio through HDMI is no issue for me.